# Group every 7 list items with JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I am trying to group list items (days) in weeks (7 days). But I am getting seven in one li, and then other seven in another li... and so on.

Can someone delight me on the right path/. :D Please What am I doing wrong?

Here it is the code https://jsfiddle.net/c2f2h9yb/354/

```
    var CurrentDate = new Date();

function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
   dateObj.setFullYear(2018, 0, 15 + numDays);
   return dateObj;
}

if (CurrentDate <= addDays(new Date(), 112)){
    document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = "We are on the first quarter";
} else if (CurrentDate <= addDays(new Date(), 224)) {
    document.getElementById('t2').innerHTML = "We are on the second quarter";
} else if (CurrentDate <= addDays(new Date(), 336)) {
        document.getElementById('t3').innerHTML = "We are on the third quarter";
}

// start and end date
var
  startDate = addDays(new Date(), 119),
  endDate = addDays(new Date(), 224);

var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };


// date array
var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
  var
    arr = new Array(),
    dt = new Date(start);

  while (dt <= end) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt).toLocaleDateString("es-ES", options));
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);

  }
  return arr;
}


var test = document.getElementById('l1');
var data = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);
var dataSlice = data.length,
    chunk = 7,
  ulelement;

var ulelement = document.createElement("ul");    
for (var i = 0; i < dataSlice; i+= chunk)
{
ulelement.innerHTML += '<li>' + data.slice( i,  i+chunk) + '</li>';
} 
test.appendChild(ulelement);
```

Comment: You are deliberately putting chunks of 7 into a single `<li>`, what *else* would the result be...?
https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wtgoma61/

Comment: @ChrisG Great solution, thanks! Yeah I never said I was good at JS. Could you explain it or put it as an answer so I can vote it?